# Multiple Layouts of Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, layout

I have a WinForms app which at this point is fully functional, about 15-20 elements on it. I would like be able to switch between two views, an 'extended' view and another being a 'simple' view.

The 'extended' view would be exactly as it is now, the 'simple' view would hide all but 1 of the controls and add 5 additional ones.

What is the best way to go about this? I am thinking that just setting `.Visible` properties one by one to hide stuff wouldn't be very good practice. I also would rather not have any duplication of controls or code.

I obviously should have thought about this at the beginning but this need just came to me. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think `Panel`container control could help in this. You could show and hide panel according to your requirements.

Comment: that or a **GroupBox** - again, very similar usage in both. or you could use the **tab control**. Plenty of different options, all of which have their merits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. I have two panels the same size and position and `axWindowsMediaPlayer` is the control that I wanted to use on both:

```
if (panelExtendedLayout.Visible)
{
    panelSimpleLayout.Visible = false;
    panelExtendedLayout.Visible = true;

    panelExtendedLayout.Controls.Remove(axWindowsMediaPlayer);
    panelSimpleLayout.Controls.Add(axWindowsMediaPlayer);
}
else
{
    panelSimpleLayout.Visible = true;
    panelExtendedLayout.Visible = false;

    panelExtendedLayout.Controls.Remove(axWindowsMediaPlayer);
    panelSimpleLayout.Controls.Add(axWindowsMediaPlayer);
}
```

This works and looks pretty seamless, video keeps playing and all other controls appear/disappear on the click of a button. I did have an initial problem where `panelSimiple` was set to the child of `panelExtended` due to my drag and dropping it onto the same space, I had to edit this in the design code.

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 Panel controls to your application and put all "simple" controls on one panel and all "extended" controls on the second panel.

```
Panel panelSimple = new Panel();
panelSimple.Location = new Point(1,1);
panelSimple.Size = new Size(500,500);
panelSimple.Controls.Add(simpleTexbox); 
panelSimple.Controls.Add...

Panel panelExtended= new Panel();
panelExtended.Location = new Point(1,1);
panelExtended.Size = new Size(500,500);
panelExtended.Controls.Add(extendedButton); 
panelExtended.Controls.Add...
```

Then just set the .Visible flag for the panels to false or true depending on which you need (you need to make sure that both wont be visible at the same time or invisible for that matter)

Comment: I understand what you are saying in theory, just struggling a bit with implementation. How do I go from what I have currently to what you are suggesting? I can't quite get my head round how I add all the items to panels in code when I already have them created.

Comment: @blawford Just set control.parent = panel.

Comment: @blawford i guess you are adding all of those Controls in the GUI right? Then you can do it the same with this.  
Just add 2 panel controls from the left drop down menu to your application and set their location and size in the propreties window to the same values. Then put the controls(textboxes, buttons etc) on the panels. The problem with this is if you have a control that is on both panels you will need to duplicate everything for it, instead if you create all your forms in the code its much easier to keep track of everything. I can make write you some short code if you want

Comment: I have the two panels, everything currently added to the first one. I had added a control to the second panel but it isn't showing as being there at a runtime. 

Can you give me an example of how to add a control that is on the first panel to the second panel? When you say "duplicate everything for it" what do you mean? I would prefer not to create every control in code manually.

Comment: Well the first panel is over the second panel if you want to see the second panel you need to hide the first one and vice verse if you set it up as them having the same location and size. And as duplicate i meant just that you either need to create another textbox, button etc with the same settings as one on the first panel and place it on the second panel. Thats why this would be much better if you made them programaticly then you just create two instances of them very easy

Comment: Could I not remove the control from the first panel and add it to the second when I change between views?

Comment: @Vajura, thanks for your help along the way, I have posted an answer for what I ended up doing which seems to work quite well.